# Mapping dataframe column to a dynamic range of values

Tags: r

I have a range of values that I would like to map classes to.

For example, if my range is

```
  c(1000,2000,3000)
```

and my dataframe is:

```
  x
  1
  5000 
  600
  1500
```

Then, I want to create a second column which maps column 'x' based on the following rules:

1) If x is bigger than everything in the range, then map to largest value in range

2) otherwise map to closest value in range *that is bigger*

For this example it would look like:

```
 x     map
 1     1000
 5000  3000
 600   1000
 1500  2000
```

I can use if statements if I know the length is fixed. But since the length is not fixed, how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply write a function which fulfills your need and `sapply` it to `df$x`, which will apply the written function to every element in `df$x`.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,5000,600,1500))

mapping_fun <- function(x) {
    # Set your vector here
    vec <- c(1000,2000,3000)
    # Determine the range of your given vector
    vec_range <- range(vec)
    # Return a value with your rules below
    if (x > vec_range[2]) {
        return(vec_range[2])
    }
    else {
        return(min(vec[vec > x]))
    }
}

df$mapping <- sapply(df$x, mapping_fun)
```

Answer (score 1):

`cut` is made for binning data. We can set the max as the max of your range, but the min to `-Inf`, and then post-hoc set any missing values to the max.

```
r = c(1:3 * 1000)
x = c(1, 5000, 600, 1500)

result = as.numeric(as.character(cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, r), labels = r)))
result[is.na(result)] = max(r)
result
# [1] 1000 3000 1000 2000
```

Comment: Wow that's neat. Is there difference between `labels = c(r)` and `labels = r` though?

Comment: No difference - that was left over when I was trying to build the `is.na` replacement into the `cut` step. Removed it now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `findInterval`

```
df1$map1 <- pmin(v1[findInterval(df1$x, v1) + 1], max(v1), na.rm = TRUE)
df1$map1
#[1] 1000 3000 1000 2000
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(1000,2000,3000)
df1 <- structure(list(x = c(1L, 5000L, 600L, 1500L)), .Names = "x", 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
list <- c(1000,2000,3000)

df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 5000, 600, 1500))

minx <- function(x){
  val <- list[list > x]
  if(length(val) == 0) {
    return(max(list))
  } else{
    return(min(val))
  }
}

df$x2 <- apply(df['x'], 1, function(x) minx(x))

df
# x   x2
# 1    1 1000
# 2 5000 3000
# 3  600 1000
# 4 1500 2000
```